# Php and tomcat configuration

Tags: php, tomcat, configuration

I have to edit some project in php to my work. I also admit that I'm completly noob in php. I try to configure php and tomcat 6.0 but without success. I making everything like in this tutorial:
http://blog.jackneer.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html
But I got an error:

> type Exception report
>
> message Wrapper cannot find servlet class net.php.servlet or a class
>   it depends on
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception  javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet
>   class net.php.servlet or a class it depends on
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> root cause  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.php.servlet
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.

I was searching on google but I don't found anything helpful. Do you know what should I do? I want to do it on tomcat but if I have to, I used different server. But which is the best to working with php? And easy to configure of course :) Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 :D I supposed that probably this is case. But I cannot find any different tutorial how to configure tomcat with php nowadays.

Comment: Ok I deicded to use IIS 8 and everything works preety nice.